# Cosa vuol dire "bummo"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto questo testo, che descrive i pensieri di Agnello a un certo punto dei fatti narrati nel libro:

> Ma Rocco glieli tiene lontani: ha giurato che finché c’è lui, nessuno alzerà un dito su Agnello che per lui è come un padre. Infatti per fortuna sono solo poliziotti. Tengono pure le manette e la pistola. Che vonno ’sti cornuti fràceti? Sono venuti a pigliarsi Rocco? Quel disgraziato di Elmer? O quel **bummo** di Coca-cola? O magari Diamante, chissà cosa ha combinato quel ragazzino.

Non ho trovato il termine "bummo" su nessun dizionario. Sapreste spiegare cosa significa? Magari si tratta di un termine regionale, possibilmente collegato al napoletano.

Dovete sapere che Coca-cola (che in realtà si chiamava Nicola) era il figlio di Agnello, che l'aveva sempre considerato come buono a nulla.

Comment: In [questo Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bummo) per il termine bummo viene indicato il significato di "persona o animale estremamente pigra".

Comment: @abarisone: Mmm... Ha senso, quindi potrebbe trattarsi di un termine italo-americano.

Answer (score 1):

In [questo Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bummo) per il termine bummo viene indicato il significato di "persona o animale estremamente pigra".

> **bummo** 
> An extremely lazy person or animal. 
> Dahlia is a bummo dog because all she does is lay on the couch all day.

Quindi sembra un'espressione gergale utilizzata nell'ambiente italo-americano descritto nel libro.

Su suggerimento di @Charo, in questo passaggio intitolato *["Col cuore in gola e la valigia di cartone legata con lo spago. La valigia dei sogni"](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/sanpietroinamantea/libri/fgagliardi/dolciricordidinfanzia.htm)* il termine bummo viene presentato come italianizzazione da parte degli emigranti italiani del termine "bum":

> E così bar diventava barro; automobile (car) diventava carro; lavoro
>   (job) giobba; negozio (shop) scioppo; ***vagabondo (bum) bummo***; scarpe
>   (shoes) sciuse; via (street) stritta; pane (bread) prete; pala
>   (shovel) sciabola; ferrovia (rail road) re erode; buca (hole) olio;
>   pavimento (floor) floro; giardino (backyard) beccaiarda; recinto
>   (fence) fenza; tetto (roof) ruffo; cantina (cellar) sello; autocarro
>   (truck) troccu; stanza (room) rummo; parcheggiare (to park) parcare;
>   gassosa (ginger ale) gingerella; assicurazione (insurance) asciuranza.
>   Per dire poi Figlio di buona donna (son of bitch) dicevano
>   sanimabicci. La pala della ferrovia diventava la sciabola del Re
>   Erode.

In questo caso *[bum](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/bum)* viene tradotto come vagabondo, anche se può anche significare scroccone, colui che vive alle spalle altrui, fannullone, scansafatiche.

Comment: Sembra si tratti dell'italianizzazione del vocabolo inglese "bum". Vedi alla fine di questa [pagina web](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/sanpietroinamantea/libri/fgagliardi/dolciricordidinfanzia.htm) il testo intitolato "Col cuore in gola e la valigia di cartone legata con lo spago. La valigia dei sogni", che parla del fenomeno dell'emigrazione in Italia.

Comment: Nel testo da te suggerito sembra indicare il termine vagabondo.

Comment: Secondo [questo dizionario](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bum), "bum" può significare "a person who avoids work and sponges on others; loafer; idler", cosa che ha perfettamente senso nel contesto del testo.